# Heroku Django selecting the settings.py

Tags: django, heroku

I'm wondering how you can select different settings.py files for different environments. What I have thought of so far is to change the `manage.py` file and add an config value such as `stage` which will correspond to the settings file name. Shown below:

**Local Host**

```
heroku config:add STAGE="project.settings.prod"
```

**Production**

```
heroku config:add STAGE="project.settings.prod"
```

So instead of the base `manage.py`:

> ```
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>     os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings.production")
>
>     from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
>
>     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
> ```

We would have:

> ```
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>     os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", os.environ['stage'])
>
>     from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
>
>     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
> ```

This feels unnature though and was looking for more information if there is a better way to handle this situation. Example of the settings folder is shown below:

```
settings/
    __init__.py
    base.py
    local.py
    staging.py
    test.py
    prod.py
```

Or is there a way to add the`--settings` option in the Procfile? Currently my Procfile is:

```
web: gunicorn project.wsgi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of defining a `stage` environment variable, you should directly define the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable, and use the original `manage.py` without modifications.

Comment: Where do I define the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable? Can you include code for this example?

Comment: In the exact same place where you define your `stage` variable.

Comment: but doesn't the normal manage.py overwrite this in the line: `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")`?

Comment: [`setdefault`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) only sets the key _if it doesn't exist_